# How to get a list of all the files edited by me?

Tags: git, github, intellij-idea

I am in the midst of a complex merge/rebase, because I would need to remove a huge amount of commits made by other people in interim branches.

I have 2 branches:

- master
- my-branch

I need to know the list of files that I personally edited in `my-branch`.

This merge is so complex that I think it is better if I:
`git checkout -b new-master` and I replace all the files edited by me, and only then I will merge it with master.

To do that I need to:
-check `my-branch` and get a list of all the files I edited in `my-branch`

Can anyone explain how to do that? It can be via terminal or also via IntelliJ step by step

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can combine `--format` and `--name-only` of [`git log`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-log) to get a list of files modified by you or any other author:

```
git log --author=youremailaddress --name-only --format='' master..my-branch
```

Add `sort -u` to remove duplicate file names from the output.

Comment: If `my-branch` was created from `my-old-branch` and `my-old-branch` was created from `my-very-old-branch` does running the command you suggested get the list of files edited by me also in previous branches, or only in the specific branch `my-branch`?

Comment: branches are pointers to revisions, @Pikk.... so when you provide a branch, it means _this revision that it is pointing to and every parent_. If you want to get revisions out of there, you need to use `^discard-this-revision-or-branch-and-its-parents`... like `git log --all ^master` to display everything that is _not_ in master branch.

Comment: @Pikk this command gets all files that have changed between two consecutive commits in the range `master..my-branch`. If you have 3 commits on `my-branch` that are not on `master`, you will get files that changes in these 3 commits.

Comment: what about if in `my-branch` some files were renamed from .js to .jsx? Or if some files were deleted in `my-branch` but are still in `master`. Will I see those files? Or to check files I deleted is a different command?

Comment: @Pikk If a commit introduced changes to a file, you will see it. If you didn't need the filter by author, you could simply run `git diff A B`, but since you specifically requested "files only changed by me", we need to filter by commits. (diff will only look at trees, log will look at commits)

Comment: @Pikk Git only ever tracks _contents_ of a file. So changing the content of a file, renaming it, deleting it, or creating it; there's no difference for Git. `git log --name-only` will show additions, removals, and modifications (and a rename is nothing more than remove + add).